# What's the meaning of this relation statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R =\{ (A,B) \ |\ A,B\ \epsilon \ P(\mathbb{N}), (A=B) \vee (A\cup\ \{ 1,2\} =B) \}$

What is the meaning of this relation? it means either of $A=B$ and $(A\cup\ { 1,2} =B)$ statements must be true?

hence it's a reflexive relation because the $A=B$ is true but the other not?

Comment: The $\lor$ symbol is the logical "or," so yes, either $A=B$ or $A\cup\{1,2\}=B$ (or both, if $1,2\in A$ already). And yes, it's reflexive because $A=A$ is always true, so $(A,A)\in R$ for all sets $A$.

Comment: Yes, you read it correctly.  Examples of sets where the first is related to the second would be $\{5\}R\{1,2,5\}$,  $\{2,3\}R\{2,3\}$, $\Bbb N R \Bbb N$ and many more.  Note however that $\{1,2,5\}$ is not related to $\{5\}$ despite $\{5\}$ being related to $\{1,2,5\}$ so it is not symmetric.  I leave the question of antisymmetry and/or transitivity to you to explore on your own.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think its anti-symmetrical but idk how to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, if $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $\mathbb N$ the the set $A$ relates to $B$ if either $A = B$ or $A$ would equal $B$ if you add $1$ and $2$ to $A$.

So $\{1,5,7,8\}R \{1,5,7,8\}$ and $\{1,5,7,8\}R \{1,2,5,7,8\}$ but $\{1,2,5,7,8\} \not R \{1,5,7,8\}$ for example.

It's *weird* relation but it's certainly a well defined relation.

It's reflexive as for all $A\subset \mathbb N$ we always have $A=A$ so $A \mathbb R$.

It's certainly not symmetric.  If $\{1,2\}\subset B$ and $A = B\setminus\{1,2\}$ then $A\cup \{1,2\}=B$ so $ARB$ but $B\ne A$ and $B\cup\{1,2\} = B\ne A$ so $B\not R A$.  (I gave a counter example in paragraph 2, but the simplest would  be $\emptyset R\{1,2\}$ but $\{1,2\}\not R \emptyset$.)

I think it's anti-symmetric.  If $A R B$ and $A\ne B$, then $A\ne A\cup \{1,2\}=B$.  So $\{1,2\}\not \subset A$ but $\{1,2\}\subset B$ so $B\ne A$ and $B\cup\{1,2\}=B\ne A$ so $B\not A$.  So $ARB$ and $BRA$ if only if $A=B$.

And I think it is Transitive.

If $A R B$ and $B RC$ then

case 1: $A = B$ than $BRC  \implies ARC$.

case 2: $A\ne B$ then $A \cup \{1,2\}= B$.  And $\{1,2\}\subset B$ so $B=B\cup \{1,2\}$.  So $B RC$ means $B = C$ or $B\cup\{1,2\}=C$ but as $B= B\cup\{1,2\}$ it follows that $B=C$.  So $ARB\implies ARC$.

So either way $ARB, BRC\implies ARC$.

Comment: what you think about this? lets assume it's not anti-symmetric so $A \neq B$ and the second condition must be always true for $ARB\ BRA$ hence always ${1,2} \subseteq A,B$ but  $ARB\ BRA$  can never work unless $A=B$ so its so supposed to be anti-symmetric